# Stop infinite loop in force download

Tags: php, codeigniter, export, force-download

While fixing a download issue related to CSV, I have added some headers that are commonly available in PHP. After, adding those I have performed a CSV export test. From that point onward in my browser, a new tab is opening & closing infinitely. I was not able to stop it by reverting the update that I have made. Cleared server & browser - cache & history. Still, the tabs are reopening while trying to export with older code. I'm now stopping the browser(Chrome) by executing `sudo pkill -9 chrome` on the terminal.

I think the new tab opening & closing is related to the force download code that I have added.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-Type: application/csv;');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', false);
header('Content-Type: application/download', false);

// file creation 
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$header = array("Group Name","Contact Name","Email","Phone Number","Company Name"); 
fputcsv($file, $header);
foreach ($new_array as $key => $line){ 
    fputcsv($file,$line); 
}
fclose($file); 
exit;
```

`$new_array` is an array of data taken from DB.

I think the issue was because of the reason that I forgotten to add cache header like:

```
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
```

Is there any way to stop this issue?

A video [link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/1190268?key=cb30c421a361afda7829fe57c3a2e18e) to see the issue

Comment: No PHP code can make tabs in the browser to open and close. If that happens, it sounds like you might have some JS script that does it for you, or that your version of chrome is buggy.

Comment: Its the action of force-download. I can see the download path to the , but no files are downloading.

Comment: What happens if you go to the download URL directly and not through any link or similar?

Comment: I have logged into another system account in my lap. There is no such issue because I have removed the download headers that I have added.

Comment: Do you mean checking the file in the download path? There is no files.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, This issue only happens when I click on the export button.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: This is a video link which is taken from my phone, https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/1190268?key=cb30c421a361afda7829fe57c3a2e18e

Comment: You seem to have two different problems. 1. There's no download (which most likely is PHP). 2. The tab keeps opening and closing (this can not be caused by PHP since PHP can't open or close tabs in the client). That looks like some JS/browser issue.

Comment: So why did it happen after adding those download header codes? Files where downloading properly in the system earlier. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/1190370?key=c4e0edc09b0dbd872f6e74c68d481cbb. I do not have made any other changes in code. If its JS or browser cache, I have cleared it all which should solve this issue.

Comment: I can't answer that, but since PHP is a server side language, it doesn't trigger events on the client.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the comments. But I have to figure it out for going forward.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Yes, you are correct. It was not the issue with PHP/JS or even with the browser. I have asked to test the CSV file by open in the browser to check the issue & I have tried the "open with" option provided by the system. And that resulted in the issue, the downloaded file after clicking the export option was trying to open in the browser window which led to downloaded the same file again & it went on like an infinite loop.
Anyway, thank you for your valuable & confident comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MagnusEriksson's comments were correct.

It was not an issue with PHP/JS or even with the browser.

I was asked to test the CSV file by open in the browser to check the issue & I have tried the "open with" option provided by the system. And that resulted in the issue, the downloaded file after clicking the export option was trying to open in the browser window which led to downloaded the same file again & it went on like an infinite loop.

This is not a code-related issue but it has taken my whole day. I have searched a lot related to PHP headers.

I'm also adding a few valuable comments from @MagnusEriksson's below:

- No PHP code can make tabs in the browser open and close.
- You seem to have two different problems. 1. There's no download (which most likely is PHP). 2. The tab keeps opening and closing (this can not be caused by PHP since PHP can't open or close tabs in the client). That looks like some JS/browser issue.